# What is the voltage and amperage rating for "Q" labeled SMD fuse?

Tags: surface-mount, fuses

I am looking for the specification for the "Q" rated SMD fuse. Since this was found on a 12V rail on a 150W graphics card I can deduce a 12A fuse *should* work but I wanted to be sure that is good "fusing theory" and if possible grab the exact match from a  major vendor.

Comment: your fusing theory is fine, that's how you would calculate the current rating of the fuse. 1 thing to note though, is this 12v rail the only thing that provides power to the GPU? because if other power rails exist, they might be contributing to the 150w power rating as well.

Comment: If the fuse is blown, there is a reason why it blew. If the reason is not fixed, the new fuse will blow too.

Comment: I blew it being stupid lets just leave it at that :D

Comment: Adoobll , You provided some good info, I forgot PCIE provided 75 Watts so this fuse would only handle 75w/12v = 6.25A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMD fuse marked Q rated 10A/125V. The exact part number is :[2410SFV10.0FM/125](https://m.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/datasheets/fuses/littelfuse_fuse_2410sfv_datasheet.pdf.pdf).